# Overfitting with batch normalization [tensorflow]?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a mid-sized conv net, neatly souped-up with batch normalization. The effect of batch normalization is tremendously positive [more than 10x training speed up and much improved accuracy].

However, there is a significant increase in the accuracy gap between training and validation/test sets, approaching 10%. This is disturbing. The gap slowly builds up during training.

The BN implementation uses the standard TF Exponential Moving Average. This does not seem to be an issue, as both validation and training sets share the same statistics and I also tried to "cold warm-up" the moving averages towards the test set statistics; this procedure had no effect.
Also, I had to turn off both l2 regularization and dropout for BN to work nicely.

Has anyone encountered similar things? Any ideas?
Are there suggestions as to how to add "more standard" regularizations to a BN-network?

Comment: The Batch Norm has very few parameters so it should not cause overfitting. Maybe you just didn't notice overfitting before because the model was not training enough time?

Comment: Thanks.Well, I'd say that BN add 2-3X in parameters, since there are shadow parameters for almost every weight. simplistically. [I also have fully connected layers, not just convolutions].

It is possible I did not notice overfitting before, yes. Without BN the network advanced much slower. But then the question remains -- how to properly regularize a BN network?

Comment: I think you misunderstand BN, there are not 2-3 times more parameters. For convolutions, BN has `2*feature_size`
 parameters (mean and variance), as the batch average is computed on all the feature map. The [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#batch_normalization) describes it well.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of this point. Again, I also have several fully connected layers, where BN adds parameters per weight. In any case, these are not fully "free " parameters. I doubt if this - the number of parameters - is the main issue here. 

I wonder how to regularize BN networks, or more generally, how to avoid overfitting in the BN case?

Comment: You are probably using Relu activations and if so there is no benefit to scaling the batch norm result by `gamma`.  So set scaling to false and you can test whether the parameter reduction matters.  I expect the first comment is correct though and the batch norm is revealing the over fitting by improving your training.

Comment: I've tried both _tanh_ instead of _relu_, and _gamma_ set to _None_ with the later. Both moves lowered overall accuracy a bit, but the gap between training and validation sets remains. Obviously, there is some overfitting. The question is how to treat it. May I please **rephrase** my question: are there issues/recommendations regarding L2 weight regularization and dropout under BN? both methods would be my first attempts to regularize my network, but they seriously misbehave under BN. [other things I'd try are lowering the depth/width of some of the layers]

Comment: I'm implementing fully connected layers with batch norm (with Lasagne/Theano) and I also see a HUGE overfitting which can't be corrected with regularization or dropout. The overfitting is HUGE.

Answer (score 0):

Batch normalization seems to be overfitting because of improper calculation of running mean and variance. This may happy if the last batch in your run over the dataset is much smaller than the rest of the batches, causing the error to accumulate over multiple epochs.

Make sure your last batch is the same size as the rest of the batches, probably by just ignoring the last batch.